# Waves node syncing very slow

Tags: wavesplatform

I'm syncing waves node from the scratch and it's very slow. I have the latest node at the time  1.1.5.

I'm already syncing for a few days and there are a lot of such messages

```
019-11-11 20:35:57,227 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-9] c.w.network.NetworkServer$ - [198faacb] connection timed out: /13.239.122.77:6868, outgoing channel count: 14
2019-11-11 20:35:58,628 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-27] c.w.n.PeerDatabaseImpl - Suspending [3a4ce078 173.212.249.18:6868]
2019-11-11 20:36:03,306 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-30] c.w.n.PeerDatabaseImpl - Suspending [be573fc2 5.181.109.139:6868]
2019-11-11 20:36:07,925 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-32] c.w.network.NetworkServer$ - [cde492ac] Connection refused: /159.65.88.42:6868, outgoing channel count: 14
2019-11-11 20:36:18,296 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-23] c.w.network.NetworkServer$ - [fe329325] connection timed out: /173.249.2.48:6868, outgoing channel count: 15
2019-11-11 20:36:27,962 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-11] c.w.n.PeerDatabaseImpl - Blacklisting [c7cda548 104.20.27.253:8080]: An invalid declared address length: 1044131688
2019-11-11 20:36:27,962 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-11] c.w.n.PeerDatabaseImpl - Suspending [c7cda548 104.20.27.253:8080]
2019-11-11 20:36:33,236 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-13] c.w.network.NetworkServer$ - [52a43f8e] Connection refused: /167.71.13.254:6868, outgoing channel count: 16
2019-11-11 20:36:37,541 INFO  [or.default-dispatcher-458] c.w.a.h.CompositeHttpService - HTTP 200 OK from GET http://localhost:6869/peers/all
2019-11-11 20:36:42,486 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-20] c.w.n.PeerDatabaseImpl - Suspending [97bb9b3a 165.22.85.76:6868]
2019-11-11 20:36:42,718 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-2] c.w.network.NetworkServer$ - [db05b6c5] connection timed out: /163.172.42.67:6868, outgoing channel count: 16
2019-11-11 20:36:45,772 INFO  [or.default-dispatcher-481] akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Request timeout encountered for request [GET /node/status Empty]
2019-11-11 20:36:47,388 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-5] c.w.network.NetworkServer$ - [824c1986] connection timed out: /163.172.69.51:6868, outgoing channel count: 15
2019-11-11 20:36:47,734 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-23] c.w.n.PeerDatabaseImpl - Suspending [07b9e1da 144.91.86.164:6868]
2019-11-11 20:36:52,713 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-9] c.w.network.NetworkServer$ - [35904c04] connection timed out: /165.227.48.133:6868, outgoing channel count: 14
2019-11-11 20:36:52,949 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-27] c.w.network.NetworkServer$ - [04f2f836] Connection refused: /167.99.208.128:6868, outgoing channel count: 14
2019-11-11 20:36:57,709 DEBUG [nio-worker-group-3-29] c.w.network.NetworkServer$ - [03342675] No route to host: /168.196.16.4:6868, outgoing channel count: 14
```

Comment: The messages look okay, what are your hardware characteristics?

Comment: 8 cpus, 16 GB ram.
I guess the problem is still there and waves command is still resolving it
https://github.com/wavesplatform/Waves/issues/2709

Answer (score 0):

You can download the blockchain state from there download. And after that import it inside the node.
The documentation explains this very well.
https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-node/options-for-getting-actual-blockchain/state-downloading-and-applying
It's a lot faster then synching.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it and it worked.
But in about a week node stop to sync and I had to do this again.

Comment: A noce should be synced in less then an hour with this import method.
You mean your node forked after a week?

Comment: If I understand correctly - no. Node worked and synced well for about a week and then stopped to sync again and was behind blockchain 100 blocks or something

Comment: Does your node run 24/7?
Does your node crash sometimes?

Comment: Yes, it runs 24/7.
I didn't find any unusual messages